# biblatex problem with two bibliography sorted differently

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a complex document which contains a lot of citations. At the end of the document, the cited papers are printed using several bibliographies that are sorted differently (some by years, other by authors).

Below is a simpler example, three biblios the first two use the default sorting scheme (by years), and the third a different sorting scheme (by authors). All the biblios use a numeric scheme and the third citation are prefixed by a `P`.

When, this document is compiled, the first set of citations is printed as "mes articles [1, 2] et des autres [0] ou [0]." and the second (after the `\newrefcontext`) is printed as "mes articles [0] et des autres [P2] ou [P1].".

My problem is that I would like the best of both: "mes articles [1, 2] et des autres [P2] ou [P1].". I used to have this working with the previous sorting option to `\printbibliography` but I'm not able to get it working with `refcontexts...`

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=latin-1,citestyle=numeric-comp,defernumbers=true,maxnames=15,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{autres.bib}
@InProceedings{1988:Felleisen:Prompt,
  author =   {Matthias Felleisen},
  title =    {The theory and practice of first-class prompts},
  crossref =     {p:1988:POPL},
  pages =    {180--190},
  doi =      {10.1145/73560.73576}
}
@Article{1990:Conic,
  author =   {Jeff Kramer and Jeff Magee},
  title =    {The evolving philosophers problem: dynamic change
                  management},
  journal =  {IEEE Transaction on Software Engineering},
  year =     1990,
  volume =   16,
  number =   11,
  pages =    {1293--1306},
  month =    nov,
  doi =      {10.1109/32.60317}
}
@Proceedings{p:1988:POPL,
  title =    {Principles of Programming Languages},
  year =     1988,
  booktitle =    {Principles of Programming Languages},
  address =  {San Diego, California, USA},
  month =    jan
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mien.bib}
@Article{TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940,
  author =   {Ali Koudri and Christophe Guychard and Sylvain
                  Guérin and Fabien Dagnat and Antoine Beugnard and
                  Joël Champeau},
  title =    {De la nécessité de fédérer des modèles dans une
                  chaîne d'outils},
  journal =  {Génie logiciel: le magazine de l'ingénierie du
                  logiciel et des systèmes},
  year =     2013,
  number =   {n\textsuperscript{o}105},
  pages =    {18 -- 23},
  month =    jun,
  langid =   {french}
}
@article{jss2016,
  TITLE =    {{Safe reconfiguration of Coqcots and Pycots
                  components}},
  AUTHOR =   {Buisson, J{\'e}r{\'e}my and Dagnat, Fabien and
                  Leroux, Elena and Martinez, S{\'e}bastien},
  JOURNAL =  {{Journal of Systems and Software}},
  PUBLISHER =    {{Elsevier}},
  YEAR =     2015,
  DOI =      {10.1016/j.jss.2015.11.039},
  KEYWORDS =     {Dynamic reconfiguration ; component model ; dynamic
                  software updating ; DSU ; Python ; Coq ; runtime
                  evolution},
  HAL_ID =   {hal-01235602},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{autres,mien}
\defbibheading{subsub}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{perso}
\addtocategory{perso}{jss2016,TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{french}
\addtocategory{french}{TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940}
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addcomma\thinspace}

\begin{document}

mes articles~\cite{TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940,jss2016} et des
autres~\cite{1990:Conic} ou~\cite{1988:Felleisen:Prompt}.

\section*{Publications personnelles}

\printbibliography[category=perso,heading=subsub,%
                    title={Articles de journal international},type=article,%
                    notcategory=french]

\printbibliography[category=perso,heading=subsub,%
                    title={Articles de journal francophone},type=article,%
                    category=french]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
mes articles~\cite{TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940,jss2016} et des
autres~\cite{1990:Conic} ou~\cite{1988:Felleisen:Prompt}.

\printbibliography[notcategory=perso,heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=true,%
                    title={Publications d'autres auteurs},prefixnumbers={P}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291772/2388 (I did not test if it works in your case, don 't have the time now).

Comment: Please see the last answer from me in the question @UlrikeFischer references. This should work with biber 2.4/biblatex 3.3 just released. The internals which are referenced in your answer are no longer the same in biblatex 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problems reusing Ulrike link. It also worked for my big document. I just adapted it to my use of categories instead of keywords.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=latin-1,citestyle=numeric-comp,defernumbers=true,maxnames=15,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifcategory{perso}{%
    \def\blx@refcontext@sorting{ydnt}\csname blx@data@\the \c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@sorting @\abx@field@entrykey\endcsname%
  }{%
    \def\blx@refcontext@sorting{nyt}\csname blx@data@\the \c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@sorting @\abx@field@entrykey\endcsname%
  }}%
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{autres.bib}
@InProceedings{1988:Felleisen:Prompt,
  author =   {Matthias Felleisen},
  title =    {The theory and practice of first-class prompts},
  crossref =     {p:1988:POPL},
  pages =    {180--190},
  doi =      {10.1145/73560.73576}
}
@Article{1990:Conic,
  author =   {Jeff Kramer and Jeff Magee},
  title =    {The evolving philosophers problem: dynamic change
                  management},
  journal =  {IEEE Transaction on Software Engineering},
  year =     1990,
  volume =   16,
  number =   11,
  pages =    {1293--1306},
  month =    nov,
  doi =      {10.1109/32.60317}
}
@Proceedings{p:1988:POPL,
  title =    {Principles of Programming Languages},
  year =     1988,
  booktitle =    {Principles of Programming Languages},
  address =  {San Diego, California, USA},
  month =    jan
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mien.bib}
@Article{TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940,
  author =   {Ali Koudri and Christophe Guychard and Sylvain
                  Guérin and Fabien Dagnat and Antoine Beugnard and
                  Joël Champeau},
  title =    {De la nécessité de fédérer des modèles dans une
                  chaîne d'outils},
  journal =  {Génie logiciel: le magazine de l'ingénierie du
                  logiciel et des systèmes},
  year =     2013,
  number =   {n\textsuperscript{o}105},
  pages =    {18 -- 23},
  month =    jun,
  langid =   {french}
}
@article{jss2016,
  TITLE =    {{Safe reconfiguration of Coqcots and Pycots
                  components}},
  AUTHOR =   {Buisson, J{\'e}r{\'e}my and Dagnat, Fabien and
                  Leroux, Elena and Martinez, S{\'e}bastien},
  JOURNAL =  {{Journal of Systems and Software}},
  PUBLISHER =    {{Elsevier}},
  YEAR =     2015,
  DOI =      {10.1016/j.jss.2015.11.039},
  KEYWORDS =     {Dynamic reconfiguration ; component model ; dynamic
                  software updating ; DSU ; Python ; Coq ; runtime
                  evolution},
  HAL_ID =   {hal-01235602},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{autres,mien}
\defbibheading{subsub}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{perso}
\addtocategory{perso}{jss2016,TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{french}
\addtocategory{french}{TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940}
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addcomma\thinspace}

\begin{document}

mes articles~\cite{TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940,jss2016} et des
autres~\cite{1990:Conic} ou~\cite{1988:Felleisen:Prompt}.

\section*{Publications personnelles}

\printbibliography[category=perso,heading=subsub,%
                    title={Articles de journal international},type=article,%
                    notcategory=french]

\printbibliography[category=perso,heading=subsub,%
                    title={Articles de journal francophone},type=article,%
                    category=french]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
mes articles~\cite{TELECOM_BRETAGNE-13940,jss2016} et des
autres~\cite{1990:Conic} ou~\cite{1988:Felleisen:Prompt}.

\printbibliography[notcategory=perso,heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=true,%
                    title={Publications d'autres auteurs},prefixnumbers={P}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With biber 2.4/biblatex 3.3, see the macros:

```
\assignrefcontextkeyws
\assignrefcontextcats
\assignrefcontextentries
```

which automatically retrieve entries with keywords, entries in a category or entrykeys themselves respectively from a refcontext.

Comment: ok I had also seen and tested your solution but it's more constraining as I need to track all cite commands and determine which refcontext they are defined in. For a pretty large document it is painful.

Comment: I agree. I will look into this to see about auto-switching the refcontext for cites.

Comment: I will add a user macro `\assignrefcontext[sorting=nty]{Nopub1,Nopub2}` to do this I think. This will automatically assign a refcontext to any cite.

Comment: Updated answer with the new biblatex 3.3 macros.